Errors implementing __eq__ method in OOP class structure
Here are a couple of classes
A parent
class GeometricShape:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.set_name(name)

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name        
    
    def set_name(self,name):
        validate_non_empty_string(name)
        self.__name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'GeometricShape(name={self.__name})'

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return(self.get_name() == other.get_name() )               


A child
class Rectangle(GeometricShape):
    def __init__(self, length, width, name='Rectangle'):
        #
        # the parent class sets the name in the constructor
        # the name is not set in the child, and we want the naming behavior
        # provided by the parents constructor
        super().__init__(name)
        #
        self.set_length(length)
        self.set_width(width)
    
    def get_length(self):
        return self.__length
        
    def get_width(self):        
        return self.__width
    
    def set_length(self,length):
        # Check the data
        validate_positive_number(length)
        self.__length = length

    def set_width(self,width):
        validate_positive_number(width)        
        self.__width  = width

    def get_perimeter (self):
       return 2 * self.__length + 2 * self.__width    
    
    def get_area (self):
       return self.__length * self.__width    
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Rectangle(a={self.__length}, b={self.__width})'     
    
    # Attempted Solution 1
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return( (self.__width == other.get_width() ) and (self.__length == other.get_length() ))
    
    # Attempted Solution 2
    #def __eq__(self, other):
    #    return( (self.__width == other.__width ) and (self.__length == other.__length )) 

I have attempted two solutions for the eq method, both fail in different ways the corresponding errors produced by each are given.
The tests for the launch of the == are being called from encrypted pye files.

Here is a description of pye files:
What is pye file in Python?
py-files containing source code. The encrypted files are unreadable and allow to protect the developer's copyrights. The encrypted files are given the extension . pye and are used if no . py file is available

Solution # 1, attempt at eq
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return( (self.__width == other.get_width() ) and (self.__length == other.get_length() ))


produces this error message:
[ERROR] 2024-07-24 GMT-0500 09:38:04.607: An unexpected error has occurred.
Traceback (most recent call last)
... then a long trace thru encrypted files ending in:
geometric_shapes.py", line 31, in eq
return(self.get_name() == other.get_name() )

Solution #2, attempt at eq:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return( (self.__width == other.__width ) and (self.__length == other.__length ))             


Produces this error message:
[ERROR] 2024-07-24 GMT-0500 09:38:04.607: An unexpected error has occurred.
Traceback (most recent call last)
... then a long trace thru encrypted files ending in:
geometric_shapes.py", line 31, in eq
return(self.get_name() == other.get_name() )

These are my tests which appear to produce the expected results:
geometric_shape  = GeometricShape('Triangle')
geometric_shape2 = GeometricShape('Triangle')
geometric_shape3 = GeometricShape('Square')
print(f'shape == shape2:{geometric_shape  == geometric_shape2}')
print(f'shape == shape3: {geometric_shape == geometric_shape3}')
#
rectangle = Rectangle(5, 3)
rectangle2 = Rectangle(5, 3)
rectangle3 = Rectangle(5, 4)
print(f'rectangle == rectangle2: {rectangle == rectangle2}')
print(f'rectangle == rectangle3: {rectangle == rectangle3}')

Which produce:
shape == shape2:True
shape == shape3: False
rectangle == rectangle2: True
rectangle == rectangle3: False

Full error message/trace thru encrypted files:
[ERROR] 2024-07-24 GMT-0500 09:38:04.607: An unexpected error has occurred.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "..submitter_utils\submitter.pye", line 70, in run
  ,$tmf-UR9QO`7m3:/ZUOC`Mr"HEG@322'^F

File ":...submitter_utils\task_handler.pye", line 31, in generate_submission_archive
  ONMZG-M0.d4^.q^W*/O-kA!&&F=,HOemS^G

File "...submitter_utils\task_handler.pye", line 51, in __list_files_for_submission
  )QtuUN&-8jD=?N"m9rd:_#TXTUSTI4'[SAo

File "...submitter_utils\task_handler.pye", line 65, in __generate_task_specific_files
  Hqt-[p'3jY=H$l-q3'VP4?99HU'p@LC(3G!

File "submitter_utils\tasks.pye", line 1040, in task6
  +9i],]UI>>n'i1TAB&tXr;9LBrMeSsA0Yg8

File "...submitter_utils\test_utils.pye", line 329, in test_class
  )JoG=k--Wumo!Ga\[2H8e?[0VI'J;#Vp@Tb

File "..submitter_utils\test_utils.pye", line 164, in test_methods
  M?*>F'c.D4-pmO:TY>Pfa?^A%oB]KD:nJ6B

File "...\ppp-p4-classes-objects\geometric_shapes.py", line 31, in __eq__

  return(self.get_name() == other.get_name() )
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_name'

The tests that fail are called from encrypted files.
My tests above behave as expected.
Any ideas?

Cannot reproduce. Please provide code you used for testing your classes.

Its encripted code

What does that mean?

Changing self.get_name' to self.get_name()' produced a different error message, updated the post to show the code change and the new error message.

It would help if you provided the error messages

Error messages are in the comments associated with the two solutions I tried.

Your code assumes your objects will never be compared to anything but another instance of the same class.

Somewhere burried in your code snippet, there is a comment that apparently includes an error message. (1) This is not a clear way to present an error message. Please include the error message in your plain text, not inside a code comment. (2) That error message refers to this code return( (self.__width == other.get_width() ) and (self.__length == other.get_length() )). But this code is nowhere in the code you have presented. Please make sure you provide code and error messages that directly relate to eachother.

The fact that tests are performed on your code using encrypted python code should not prevent you to write your own test and reproduce the problem. Please provide your code that you have written to work with these classes and which reproduces the error.

Idiomatic Python doesn't use a bunch of name-mangled attribute and dedicated setters and getters. The default choice is public attributes, which can be replaced with properties that operate on "private" (_length) attributes as necessary.

Those error messages are incomplete; they only show where the error occurs, not what the error actually is.

The error messages refer to encrypted files.

you're asking many questions at the same time. for non encrypted files, your code works as intended.

Could you please include the full error message, probably multiple lines since it currently only tells the location but not the actual error.
Note on Solution 2, there aren't many limitations in Pythons code, but I thing that will not work is accessing attributes with double underscores from outside a class. (There are ways, but all attributes prefixed with __ should be considered private, and thereby shouldn't be accessed from outside the class.)
Therefor, self.__width == other.__width will raise a error for not knowing other.__width even if other would have the __width attribute.
You could try and launch a debugger window where you put a break-point right at the check itself.
A commonly used defensive technique when implementing dunder methods is using the isinstance method, like so
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Rectangle):
        return(self.__width == other.get_width() and self.__length == other.get_length())
    elif isinstance(other, GeometricShape):
        return super().__eq__(other)
    return False

This would prevent you from calling certain methods which are not implemented in the other object.

Could you please include the full error message if you need more info, you can't write a good answer
